# Solving for theta

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve some a math problem in a 3D software project.

I know that:

$$\cos(\theta)\sin(75°)a+\cos(75°)b+\sin(\theta)\sin(75°)c=0$$

How do I write an equation to solve for $\theta$? Could someone go through all the steps please? Because I have to solve many similar problems.

I already know that there may be zero, one, or (usually) two solutions.

Thanks.

[edit]

By the way, what would the solutions for $\theta$ be in this case if a = 4, b = 5, and c = 6? (Just so I can work it out on my own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Notice the common factor of $\sin(75^\circ)$. Write
$$a\cos\theta + c\sin\theta = \sqrt{a^2+c^2}\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}} \cos\theta + \frac c{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}\sin\theta\right).$$
There is an angle $\tau$ with
$$\cos\tau = \frac c{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}} \quad\text{and}\quad \sin\tau=\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}.$$
Now you can use the addition formula for $\sin$ to express the term in parentheses as $\sin(\theta+\tau)$.

Comment: Is the "addition formula for sin" a special formula I should know about already?

Comment: If you've studied trigonometry, yes. You can find it easily enough!

Comment: I found it, thanks. But before that I don't understand how you get to `acosθ+csinθ`. What happened to `bcos(75)`?

Comment: Oh, it's still there, on the other side of the equation. In fact, divide by $\sin(75^\circ)$ and you have our expression for $a\cos\theta+c\sin\theta = -b\cot(75^\circ)$, right?

Comment: You're skipping over a lot of stuff...

Comment: I have to assume you know basic algebra if you're working on a question like this. We can't guess you know nothing.

Comment: By the way, what would the solutions for θ be in this case if a = 4, b = 5, and c = 6? (Just so I can work it out on my own.)

Comment: No guarantees, but my trusty calculator gives $\theta \approx -33.88^\circ$. Most math/engineering folks would work in radians, btw.

Comment: I got θ ≈ 24.9 and θ ≈ -46.9 so I must have done something wrong. Anyway, I forgot that a, b and c are supposed to be between -1 and +1.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's only their ratios that matter. You can rescale the equation.

Comment: I think we're both wrong, but you're closer. $-44.4^\circ$.

Comment: I rounded to 3 decimal places at each step in the problem. That may be why. There should be two solutions however.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known constants. So are the $\sin$ and $\cos$ of $75^\circ$. So you want to solve an equation of the form
$$
r\cos \theta + s \sin \theta + t = 0
$$
for $\theta$ in terms of $r$, $s$ and $t$.

Write
$$
r \cos \theta = r\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} = 
- s \sin \theta - t.
$$

Square both sides of that equation and solve the resulting quadratic equation for $\sin \theta$.